# Yahoo as Exchange on IOS 4

Tags: iphone, exchange-activesync, yahoo

I can sync Gmail contacts to my iPhone and it works pretty well.

Is there a way I can sync my Yahoo contacts over the air with my iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that with IOS 5 it is possible to sync contacts with Yahoo